# Can't sort 3 columns in MVC 4 - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, sorting

Normal sorting works if I just implement the sorting on 2 columns, in this example "Bedrag" & "Datumbetaling".

When I want to add sorting on a third column called "StatusBetalingID" then It only sorts Descending if I click on the column, if I click on this column a second time, It wouldn't sort ascending. 
When I keep clicking on the first 2 columns "Bedrag" & "DatumBetaling" then It keeps sorting ascending & descending.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortBy)
{
    ViewBag.SortBedragParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Bedrag_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.SortDatumParameter = sortBy == "DatumBetaling" ? "DatumBetaling_desc" : "DatumBetaling";
    ViewBag.SortStatusParameter = sortBy == "StatusBetaling" ? "stat" : "Status_desc";
    var betalingen = betalingBLL.GetAll();
    switch (sortBy)
    {
       case "Bedrag_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bedrag);
                break;
       case "DatumBetaling_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.DatumBetaling);
                break;
       case "DatumBetaling":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.DatumBetaling);
                break;
        case "Status_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusBetalingID);
                break;
        case "stat":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.StatusBetalingID);
                break;
        default:
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.Bedrag);
                break;
     }
     return View(betalingen.ToList());
}
```

Here is the code in the view:

```
<th> <%: Html.ActionLink("Status Betaling", "Index", new { sortBy = ViewBag.SortStatusParameter}) %> </th>
<th> <%:Html.ActionLink("Datum Betaling", "Index", new { sortBy =  ViewBag.SortDatumParameter}) %> </th>
<th> <%:Html.ActionLink("Bedrag", "Index", new { sortBy = ViewBag.SortBedragParameter }) %> </th>
```

So it actually works, the sorting, but I don't know how to solve the problem with the third parameter/column to keep sorting this one.

Comment: You would maybe be better off with something for sorting client side. I have used [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and it works well. Saves a lot of callbacks to your Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that sortby will never equal `StatusBetaling` (why would it) and thus this line will always be set to `Status_desc`:

```
ViewBag.SortStatusParameter = sortBy == "StatusBetaling" ? "stat" : "Status_desc";
```

The following code should do it:

```
ViewBag.SortBedragParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Bedrag_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.SortDatumParameter = sortBy == "DatumBetaling" ? "DatumBetaling_desc" : "DatumBetaling";
    ViewBag.SortStatusParameter = sortBy == "StatusBetaling" ? "Status_desc" : "StatusBetaling";
    var betalingen = betalingBLL.GetAll();
    switch (sortBy)
    {
       case "Bedrag_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bedrag);
                break;
       case "DatumBetaling_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.DatumBetaling);
                break;
       case "DatumBetaling":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.DatumBetaling);
                break;
        case "Status_desc":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusBetalingID);
                break;
        case "StatusBetaling":
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.StatusBetalingID);
                break;
        default:
                betalingen = betalingen.OrderBy(x => x.Bedrag);
                break;
     }
     return View(betalingen.ToList());
```